# One-sided Dirichlet approximation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

A version of [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) states: Given $d \in \mathbb{R}$ and an integer $N \geq 2$, there exist integers $p$ and $q$ with $p > 0$ such that
$$ |pd - q | \leq \frac{1}{N}.$$
Is the result also true for the version without the absolute value? In other words, do there exist integers $p$ and $q$ with $p > 0$ such that
$$ 0 \leq pd - q \leq \frac{1}{N}?$$

Comment: Yes. And you can prove it by assuming the first result. IE If you have such a $(p,q)$ with $ -1/N \leq pd-q \leq 0 $, consider what happens with $ (Np, Nq - k)$ for a suitable $k$. Play with the coefficients as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Calvin. This construction would lead to $-1 + k \leq Npd - (Nq - k) \leq k$. However, it seems impossible to me to find a $k$ that is both integer and leads to a precision of $\frac{1}{N}$ on the right hand side... Could you please clarify the $k$ you had in mind? Thanks!

Comment: Show that there exists a $l$ such that $ - 1 \leq l(pd - q) \leq -(N-1)/N$. Corollary: $ 0 \leq lpd  - lq + 1 \leq 1/N$. $\quad$ That's what I meant by "play with the coefficients as needed", which you were starting to get, but weren't thinking of changing the relevant one (bad notation on my part).

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!